# How to iterate to obtain values in each iteration and to return them in a list

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a list of people and I want to get the number of people grouped by years that the property date is in that year.
The problem is that the amount of years I want to look for is from the current backwards I wish the user to select it.
Currently I get the information for 10 years ago but I wish the user can enter any number of years.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convertidos_neto_10_year_ago(IN aidiglesia integer)

  RETURNS TABLE(cant0 bigint, cant1 bigint, cant2 bigint, cant3 bigint, cant4 bigint, cant5 bigint, cant6 bigint, cant7 bigint, cant8 bigint, cant9 bigint, cant10 bigint) AS

$BODY$BEGIN

RETURN Query SELECT

 ( SELECT  count(jb_persona.id)
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (10)::double precision))) ,

 ( SELECT count(jb_persona.id)
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (9)::double precision)))) ,

( SELECT count(jb_persona.id) AS count3
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (8)::double precision)))) ,

( SELECT count(jb_persona.id) AS count4
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (7)::double precision))))  ,

 ( SELECT count(jb_persona.id) AS count5
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (6)::double precision)))) ,

 ( SELECT count(jb_persona.id) AS count5
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (5)::double precision)))) ,

( SELECT count(jb_persona.id) AS count5
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (4)::double precision)))) ,

  ( SELECT count(jb_persona.id) AS count5
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (3)::double precision)))) ,

 ( SELECT count(jb_persona.id) AS count5
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (2)::double precision)))) ,

( SELECT count(jb_persona.id) AS count5
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (1)::double precision)))) ,

 ( SELECT count(jb_persona.id) AS count5
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia) AND (date_part('year'::text, jb_persona.fecha_conversion) = (date_part('year'::text, ('now'::text)::date) - (0)::double precision))));  

END;

$BODY$

  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;

ALTER FUNCTION convertidos_neto_10_year_ago(integer)

 OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: so you want a dynamic number of columns returned by function depending on that function argument?..

Comment: Variable number of columns is not easy & requires a special call syntax (PostgreSQL's engine needs to know how many columns will be returned from the call -- and with which type exactly). -- Why not just `WHERE date_part('year', fecha_conversion) + 10 >= date_part('year', now()) GROUP BY date_part('year', fecha_conversion)` ? (That will result in multiple rows instead of multiple columns)

Comment: yes, @VaoTsun. but can be one colunm and dinamic row count. if year count is 10, then one column and 10 rows...

Comment: @pozs, Explain a little more your proposal please

Comment: then definitely go for one column with n rows for n years!

Comment: @meyquel that way you could return results in f.ex. `TABLE(year int, count bigint)` format, with values like `(2017, 1234), (2016, 2345)`

Comment: `SELECT distinct count(jb_persona.id) over (partition by date_trunc('year', fecha)), date_trunc('year', fecha)
           FROM jb_persona
          WHERE ((jb_persona.id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia)`

Comment: I'm doing it right now...

Comment: thanks... it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To also have zero count years at the output outer join a generated year series:

```
select to_char(d, 'YYYY') as year, count(id) as total
from
    jb_persona
    right join
    generate_series(
        date_trunc('year', now() - interval '10 years'),
        now(), interval '1 year'
    ) gs(d) on gs.d = date_trunc('year', fecha_conversion)
where id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia
group by 1
```

If you want that as columns the easiest solution it to have it as json:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(year, total)
from (
    select to_char(d, 'YYYY') as year, count(id) as total
    from
        jb_persona
        right join
        generate_series(
            date_trunc('year', now() - interval '10 years'),
            now(), interval '1 year'
        ) gs(d) on gs.d = date_trunc('year', fecha_conversion)
    where id_iglesiafk = aidiglesia
    group by 1
) s
```

For 9.4 use:

```
select jsonb_object(array_agg(year), array_agg(total::text))
from ...
```

Comment: Netto, thanks you but:  [Err] ERROR:  no existe la función jsonb_object_agg(text, bigint)
LINE 1: select jsonb_object_agg(years, total)
               ^
HINT:  Ninguna función coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos.

Comment: @meyquel What is the Postgresql version?

Comment: postgres 9.4 version

Comment: @meyquel Edited with a 9.4 solution

Comment: @meyquel Adapted to zero count years